# DateTime calculations in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 columns in a table in my database - `Created`, `Expires` and `Expiration_Interval`. Both `Created` and `Expires` are `datetimeoffset(0)` and `Expiration_Interval` is of data type `Time(0)`.

`Created` gets populated with `SYSUTCDATETIME()`, when inserting a new row. Data for `Expiration_Interval` is provided in the input XML in `hh:mm:ss` format, extracted and populated. The requirement is to populate `Expires` column with `Created+Expiration_Interval`. Here is my approach:

```
  INSERT INTO SESSIONS
  SELECT 
    Expiration_Interval,
    SYSUTCDATETIME(),
    DATEADD(s,((DATEPART(hh,Timeout)*3600)+(DATEPART(mi,Timeout)*60)+    DATEPART(ss,Timeout)),SYSUTCDATETIME())
  FROM input_xml -- CTE with shredded XML data
```

Is there an easier way to do this? This is on SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: "an easier way" - easier in what way?

Comment: Maybe easier is not the right word. More efficient way?

Comment: More efficient  than what? where is your benchmark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast `Timeout` to `datetime` and use `+` to add time to `SYSUTCDATETIME()`.

```
SYSUTCDATETIME()+cast(Timeout as datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hate to say:

```
declare @Time as Time = '01:00:00.00'
declare @NoTime as Time = '00:00:00.00'
declare @Now as DateTimeOffset = SysDateTimeOffset()

select @Now as 'Now', @Time as 'One Hour',
    DateDiff( s, @NoTime, @Time ) as 'One Hour in Seconds',
    DateAdd( s, DateDiff( s, @NoTime, @Time ), @Now ) as 'One Hour Hence'
```

Tip: I generally capture "now" in a variable and then use it throughout a query or stored procedure.  It avoids multiple function calls and keeps things synchronized.  Unless, of course, it is an unusually long running wad of code and you really want to watch the progress.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you store the interval as an integer (seconds). You'd then only need to do the following:

```
DATEADD(s, Expiration_Interval, Created)
```